# How to add Audio into QGIS recorded and geotagged using OSMand app

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, osmand

Is there a plugin or easy way of adding audio recordings, recorded and tagged using OSMand app, into QGIS.
I'm using a PC and have no coding knowledge! 
I was able to  load the photographs using the "load photos" plugin then pop them up using the eVis plugin. 
I understand that I could also use eVis for audio but seems to require a database set up which I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

I am just a beginner, and I dont think this is the best way, but it works - so here is my solution:

1. import the gpx-file as a new layer into qgis, which osmand exports with all the audio-files and pictures
2. export this new layer as a new shp-file from qgis and import it again into qgis - now you can edit this layer;
3. in the attribute table you can see now all the notes from osmand
4. insert a new column (e.g. "path") into the attribute table and fill in the absolute or relative file-paths on your pc to the notes
5. start the evis-event browser; in "configure external applications" you can set up for the audio files (3gp files) that qgis should use VLC-Player (or any other player)
6. Finished! With the eVis event tool you can click on the layer Points. Images will be shown in the small window; With audio files you have to click on the path and your media player will launch...

If you have a lot of notes I used the following method:

1. Use [directory printer](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/DirPrintOK) to print a excel (CVS) sheet with information (absolute or relative path to the notes) of all the notes
2. add some kind of matching ID in this list so that you can Join this list with your points layer in QGIS
3. import this list as text layer to qgis
4. use JOIN-function to add the path information from the excel sheet (CSV) to the point layer

Comment: Thank you, will have a go ASP, posted the question quite a while back and gave up. appreciate advice

Comment: Let me know if it works, otherwise i will add some screenshots of my workaround or give some more detailed info...